# How to remove docker installed using wget?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, docker, uninstallation

I've installed docker following installation tutorial on docker.com, using `wget https://get.docker.com/ | sh` command.
Now i need to remove it entirely. `apt-get remove docker`, `apt-get --auto-remove docker`, `apt-get remove docker.io`, `apt-get --auto-remove docker.io` or any other combination doesn't work, since I didn't install it using apt-get. Is there any way to remove docker faster than removing it by hand?

(I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04 if it makes any difference).

Answer (score 191, accepted):

The [uninstallation step](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/) mentions:

```
sudo apt-get purge -y docker-engine
sudo apt-get autoremove -y --purge docker-engine
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Note: [chasmani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2780744/chasmani) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31313497/how-to-remove-docker-installed-using-wget/31313851?noredirect=1#comment78629167_31313851):

> I had to also add `docker-ce`, `docker.io` and `docker` to the first two lines to completely get rid of

```
sudo apt-get purge -y docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce
sudo apt-get autoremove -y --purge docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce
```

It adds:

> The above commands will not remove images, containers, volumes, or user created configuration files on your host. If you wish to delete all images, containers, and volumes run the following command:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
```

> Remove docker from apparmor.d:

```
sudo rm /etc/apparmor.d/docker
```

> Remove docker group:

```
sudo groupdel docker
```

As [Micah Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2514228/micah-smith) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31313497/how-to-remove-docker-installed-using-wget/31313851?noredirect=1#comment72970399_31313851):

> You may (as I did) also need to remove runtime files such as `/var/run/docker.sock`.
>   Try `find / -name '*docker*'` to see all of these files. (This searches your entire filesystem, look in at least `/var`, `/run`, `/etc` separately if you prefer not to do this.)

Now, You have successfully deleted docker.

Comment: You may (as I did) also need to remove runtime files such as `/var/run/docker.sock`. Try `find / -name '*docker*'` to see all of these files. (This searches your entire filesystem, look in at least `/var`, `/run`, `/etc` separately if you prefer not to do this.)

Comment: Thanks, I had to also add docker-ce, docker.io and docker to the first two lines to completely get rid of it. E.g. first line is `sudo apt-get purge -y docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce`

Comment: @chasmani Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @MicahSmith removing runtime files is also important as it might crash the new installations if we do not remove those runtime files. Thanks. Your one point fixed my issue.

Comment: @GauravSharma I agree. I have included Micah's comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: the codes mentioned in "I had to also add", worked for me, that includes all sorts of package