# How to remove docker completely from ubuntu 14.04

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, uninstallation

I installed Docker on Ubuntu a while back but when I tried to remove, the Docker still exists in the system. I followed this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31313851/2340159 but didn't work.

Comment: What exactly didn't work?

Comment: @Grimmy Thanks and kindly refer my answer

Comment: sudo rm -r /   (problems dissapear)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Apparently, the system I was using had the **docker-ce** not Docker. Thus, running below command did the trick.

`sudo apt-get purge docker-ce`

`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker`

hope it helps

Comment: If you have made some configuration changes to docker(like me). You might want to consider `sudo rm -rf /etc/docker` as well.

Answer (score 92):

Probably your problem is that for Docker that has been installed from default Ubuntu repository, the package name is `docker.io`

Or package name may be something like `docker-ce`. 
Try running

```
dpkg -l | grep -i docker
```

to identify what installed package you have

So you need to change package name in commands from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31313851/2340159  to match package name. For example, for `docker.io` it would be:

```
sudo apt-get purge -y docker.io
sudo apt-get autoremove -y --purge docker.io
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

It adds:

> The above commands will not remove images, containers, volumes, or user created configuration files on your host. If you wish to delete all images, containers, and volumes run the following command:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
```

> Remove docker from apparmor.d:

```
sudo rm /etc/apparmor.d/docker
```

> Remove docker group:

```
sudo groupdel docker
```

Comment: Hi @Dmitriusan, Thank you for the prompt answer. Apparently the system I was using had the docker-ce not Docker. Thus, running sudo apt-get purge docker-ce did the trick

Comment: You forgot `sudo rm -rf /etc/docker` and _then_ run `apt-get purge` .. otherwise it leaves a `pc` entry in the apt repos (`dpkg -l` still sees it). Also, you probably also want to remove `runc` and `containerd` which are installed by docker.io, so `sudo apt-get purge runc containerd docker.io` ... unless you already had `runc` and/or `containderd` before installing docker.io.

Comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/6077 this helped for in-between issue

Answer (score 2):

**@miyuru**. As suggested by him run all the steps.

**Ubuntu version 16.04**

Still when I ran `docker --version` it was returning a version. So to uninstall it completely

Again run the `dpkg -l | grep -i docker` which will list package still there in system.

For example:

```
ii  docker-ce-cli      5:19.03.6~3-0~ubuntu-xenial               
amd64        Docker CLI: the open-source application container engine
```

Now remove them as show below :

```
sudo apt-get purge -y docker-ce-cli

sudo apt-get autoremove -y --purge docker-ce-cli

sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Hope this will resolve it, as it did in my case.

Answer (score 1):

This removes "docker.io" completely from ubuntu
    `sudo apt-get purge docker.io`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
```