# Remove Docker on ubuntu 18

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04, pos

I had installed docker in ubuntu 18 and now wants to remove everything for a clean install. Had used :   `sudo apt-get install docker.io`

This stackoverflow thread (though not meant for my exact installation) has a part-solution: [docker remove answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31313497/how-to-remove-docker-installed-using-wget?answertab=active#tab-top)

The only problem is that it doesn't mention how to remove other remaining docker files after running `find / -name '*docker*'` . There are so many in my system!   [screenshot_1 after "find / -name **docker** "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GVR5.png)  >> [screenshot_2 after "find / -name **docker** "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYJXI.png)

Additionally, I am looking for simple, hassle-free steps to install opensourcePOS on ubuntu 18 (Local deploy) [git osPOS](https://github.com/opensourcepos/opensourcepos) . The ones on git and osPOS website are for advanced users I guess - they leave a lot of details. Any links?

Comment: It might be worth asking this question on the Ubuntu Stack Exchange site, https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get purge -y docker.io 

sudo apt-get autoremove -y --purge docker.io

sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker

sudo rm -rf /etc/docker

sudo rm /etc/apparmor.d/docker

sudo apt-get purge runc containerd docker.io
```

Comment: even after executing above commands, i can see docker binary and other related binaries: `docker, dockerd, dockerd-rootless-setuptool.sh, dockerd-rootless.sh, docker-init, docker-proxy` on ubuntu 18.04 what else to do for complete uninstall @VinDev ?

Comment: for now i have manually removed each of the above binaries

Answer (score 0):

You can easily remove docker on linux by nautilus:

1. Open Nautilus.
2. Go to Other Locations.
3. Go to Computer.
4. Search Docker.
5. Select All the Files docker and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the command docker suggests to use if you want to remove docker. I used it in ubuntu 18

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#uninstall-docker-engine

sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc

Comment: You say that's the command docker suggests. In this case it would be a good idea to provide the link to support your answer.